# SciKeras - RandomizedSearchCV for best hyper-parameters

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to follow the example on chapter 10 of the book *Hands-On Machine Learning with SciKit-Learn, Keras and TensorFlow* which regard the optimization of the hyperparameters of a DNN model.

The dataset is the MNIST fashion model and the goal of the project is the classification of the images in 10 classes.

```
(X_train_full, y_train_full), (X_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
```

There is no validation, so I'm going to create that set using the first 5k elements:

```
X_valid, X_train = X_train_full[:5000], X_train_full[5000:]
y_valid, y_train = y_train_full[:5000], y_train_full[5000:]
```

A possible implementation of a simple DNN model is the following, using sequential Keras API:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=[28, 28]))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(300, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(200, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
```

The book then suggests to study the hyper-parameter space to found the best ones, using `RandomizedSearchCV`. The example uses `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasRegressor` which is now deprecated in favor of `KerasRegressor` by SciKeras.

I created a function containing the ML model:

```
input_shape=X_train[0].shape
def build_model(n_hidden = 1, n_neurons = 30, learning_rate=3e-3, input_shape=input_shape):
    grid_model = keras.models.Sequential()
    grid_model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=input_shape))
    for layer in range(n_hidden):
        grid_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(n_neurons, activation="relu"))
    grid_model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    grid_model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"])
    return grid_model
```

Then I defined the model hyperparameters to explore:

```
param_distribs = {
    "n_hidden": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    "n_neurons": np.arange(1, 300),
    "learning_rate": reciprocal(3e-4, 3e-2)
}
```

I then used SciKeras to create a wrapper around the Keras model, feeding the parameter space:

```
keras_reg = KerasRegressor(build_model, n_hidden=param_distribs["n_hidden"], n_neurons=param_distribs["n_neurons"], learning_rate=param_distribs["learning_rate"], verbose=1)
```

The last step is to define a `RandomizedSearchCV` object and start the research using the `fit` method:

```
rnd_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(keras_reg, param_distribs, n_iter=10, cv=3)

rnd_search_cv.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, validation_data=(X_valid, y_valid), callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=10)])
```

This last row gives me the following error, for each epoch:

```
/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py:776: UserWarning: Scoring failed. The score on this train-test partition for these parameters will be set to nan. Details: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py", line 767, in _score
    scores = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
  File "/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py", line 429, in _passthrough_scorer
    return estimator.score(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py", line 1100, in score
    return self.scorer(y, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight, **score_args)
  File "/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scikeras/wrappers.py", line 1697, in scorer
    return sklearn_r2_score(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs)
  File "/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py", line 911, in r2_score
    y_type, y_true, y_pred, multioutput = _check_reg_targets(
  File "/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_regression.py", line 100, in _check_reg_targets
    check_consistent_length(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/docker_user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 387, in check_consistent_length
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [18334, 183340]
```

A factor 10 on the second dimension makes me thinking... I also checked the shapes of  the data and they are fine...

```
print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
(55000, 28, 28) (55000,)
```

Can you please help me dealing with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the name suggests, [`scikeras.wrappers.KerasRregressor`](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/generated/scikeras.wrappers.KerasRegressor.html) should be employed for regression and uses the `r2_score` by default. Hence, it will not convert the softmax output to a class index like the ones you have in your validation set. The last dense layer's output is of size `10` (hence the factor of 10). Instead, you should use [`scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier`](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/generated/scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier.html) that uses accuracy as scoring by default. Simply swapping `KerasRegressor` out for `KerasClassifier` should make it work.